# Can one add 'likely plagiarism' on the close a question option?

Tags: discussion, support

Questions and answers can easily be plagiarised.

There ought to be some way of saying so.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you have evidence of plagiarism you should flag the post with a custom flag & link to the evidence.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a comment, just raise a custom flag for moderators to take care of. Just make sure to include in your tag where the original source is that is being plagiarized.